# Is there any way to either extend iOS background runtime a bit longer than 30s, or to call a background function in a minute or so to run once?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a app that starts in the background, and since **iOS 13** gets about 30s of background runtime using **beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler)**. I am trying to fetch data from an external service that takes about 40s to calculate its final output, so I need to extend background fetch and set a DispatchQueue for 40-60s later, or directly call the function in background 60s later.

I have looked up **Background fetch**, but I don't think it is adequate, for it fetched data forever (and on big time intervals), while I only need it 1 minute after the background calculations have finished.

I also looked at similar posts, which where outdated saying iOS could background task for 3 or 10 minutes as it could before iOS 13 and iOS 7

For context, the app receives a BLE packet in background making the app background task for about 30s, and sends the received data to a server which makes certain calculations, updating a GET http method which gives the app its final results

Clarification: I don't have access or can modify the server.

If there is not a way, is there any similar methods of doing the same thing?

Comment: You might be able to get your server to send a push notification when the task is complete. You can't extend background execution time.

Comment: I forgot to add i cant change the functionnality of the server, it is external to me. I am currently lookin using a localNotification as a background timer

Comment: Then you should fetch the data next time you come to the foreground and/or the next time you are launched in the background by BLE data

Comment: It currently does that. Could i use Local Notifications and  **didReceiveLocalNotification** in app delegate as a background timer ?

Comment: No, because your app doesn't execute when a local notification  is delivered.